# Gatling 3.4 bug with timeout after silent check

Tags: websocket, gatling

I experience a very weird behavior of Gatling with websocket silent check:
The .await(600 seconds)(check) fails with timeout after some milliseconds.

At first I explain my situation. The limitation of Gatling websocket does not allow to handle ping requests from server. So I have to cheat and invented a fancy protocol. The code with comments is below:

1. client may send an INITIAL event or NON-INITIAL event (not first in a sequence).
2. the minimum interval between INITIAL events is 3 seconds
3. each request initialized by client results with 2 responses: "calculation started" and "calculation result"
4. ping request from server may come at any time. When we pause between client events, we still may receive ping request
5. when we receive a ping request, we must respond.
6. the usual sequence of events does not depend on ping, so if ping arrived, then we must wait for one more message

```
exec(session => dump(session, s"The spin action: event=$eventType oneRound=$oneRound" )).
        exec(_.remove(ATTR_PING_SEQ_ID))
        .doIfOrElse("CLIENT_INITIAL_EVENT".equals(eventType)) {
          exec(session => dump(session, s"Sending CLIENT_INITIAL_EVENT and expect 2 or 3 responses. 3 responses mean that one of them is a ping. wait for each response for ${Config.waitForResponseSec} seconds" )).
            exec(
              clientActionBuilder
                // first response: "started calculation"
                .await(Config.waitForResponseSec seconds)(check1)
                // second response: "calculated result"
                .await(Config.waitForResponseSec seconds)(check2)
                // wait for the delay between client initial events.
                // We cannot just wait because PING may come within this time and we must handle it!
                // Most probably the ping will not come, so we ignore the timeout and make the check silent
                .await(Config.minTimeBetweenClientInitialEventsMillis milliseconds)(check3.silent)
            )
            .exec(session => dump(session, s"SPIN 2 or 3 responses got" ))
            // we waited for 3 messages, so if the ping came, we just send pong and do not wait for anything else
            .doIf(session => Utils.getStringSessionAttribute(session, ATTR_PING_SEQ_ID, "0") != "0"){
              exec(session => dump(session, s"Sending PONG for CLIENT_INITIAL_EVENT" )).
                exec(pongBuilder)
            }
        } {
          exec(session => dump(session, s"Sending NON-INITIAL_CLIENT_EVENT and expect 2 responses" )).
            exec(
              clientActionBuilder
                // first response: "started calculation"
                .await(Config.waitForResponseSec seconds)(check4)
                // second response: "calculation result"
                .await(Config.waitForResponseSec seconds)(check5)
            )
            .exec(session => dump(session, s"NON-INITIAL_CLIENT_EVENT 2 responses got" ))
            // we waited for 2 messages. If ping came, then it came instead of a
            // "started calculation" or "calculation result", so we have to wait for one more message
            .doIf(session => Utils.getStringSessionAttribute(session, ATTR_PING_SEQ_ID, "0") != "0"){
              exec(session => dump(session, s"Sending PONG for NON-INITIAL_CLIENT_EVENT" )).
                exec(pongBuilder.await(Config.waitForResponseSec seconds)(check6))
                .exec(session => dump(session, s"NON-INITIAL_CLIENT_EVENT PONG response got" ))
            }
        }
        .exitHereIfFailed
        .exec(_.remove(ATTR_PING_SEQ_ID))
```

The check for each message is the same. It is cloned because I want to see in logs which concrete check has timed out:

```
val checkX = ws.checkTextMessage("myCheckX")
        .matching(jsonPath(matchingCondition).exists)
          jsonPath("$.body.data.nextActions[0]").optional.saveAs(ATTR_NEXT_ACTION),
        ).check(regex("\"cId\":(.*?),(\"name\":\"Ping\")").optional.saveAs(ATTR_PING_SEQ_ID))
```

the actual messages are very simple:

```
val clientActionBuilder = ws("requestClientAction").sendText(
        """{
          |   "header":
          |   {
          |     "name": "Action",
          |     "cId": ${cId},
          |     "dType": 2
          |   },
          |   "body":
          |   {
          |     "type": "@TYPE@",
          |     "seqId":${seqId},
          |     "data":{
          |      }
          |   }
          |}
    """.stripMargin.replaceAll("[\\s\n\r]", "").replace("@TYPE@", eventType)
      )

val pongBuilder = ws("requestPong").sendText(
        """{
          |   "header":
          |   {
          |     "name": "Ping",
          |     "cId": ${pingSeqId},
          |     "dType": 1
          |   },
          |   "body": {}
          |}
      """.stripMargin.replaceAll("[\\s\n\r]", "")
      )
```

the client actions are sent in a loop untill timeout:

```
asLongAs(
      session =>
        !timeoutIsOver(startTime, testDurationMillis)
    ) {
    exec(doClientAction())

}
```

The logic works as expected until the ping request comes from server. After that the ws await timeout breaks. Here is what I see in logs:

```
DUMP---> The client action: event=INITIAL_EVENT oneRound=false
DUMP---> Sending CLIENT_INITIAL_EVENT and expect 2 or 3 responses. wait for each response for 600 seconds
20:33:18.772 [INFO ] i.g.h.a.w.WsSendTextFrame - Sending text frame {"header":{"name":"Action","cId":103,"dType":2},"body":{}} with websocket 'gatling.http.webSocket': Scenario 'doUntilTimeout', UserId #1
20:33:18.773 [DEBUG] i.g.h.a.w.f.WsIdleState - Send text frame requestClientAction {"header":{"name":"Action","cId":103,"dType":2},"body":{}}
20:33:18.773 [DEBUG] i.g.h.c.i.WebSocketHandler - ctx.write msg=TextWebSocketFrame(data: UnpooledByteBufAllocator$InstrumentedUnpooledUnsafeHeapByteBuf(ridx: 0, widx: 164, cap: 512))
20:33:18.773 [TRACE] i.n.h.c.h.w.WebSocket08FrameEncoder - Encoding WebSocket Frame opCode=1 length=164
20:33:18.773 [DEBUG] i.g.h.a.w.f.WsIdleState - Trigger check after sending text frame
20:33:18.787 [TRACE] i.n.h.c.h.w.WebSocket08FrameDecoder - Decoding WebSocket Frame opCode=1
20:33:18.787 [TRACE] i.n.h.c.h.w.WebSocket08FrameDecoder - Decoding WebSocket Frame length=80
20:33:18.787 [DEBUG] i.g.h.c.i.WebSocketHandler - Read msg=TextWebSocketFrame(data: PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf(ridx: 0, widx: 80, cap: 80))
20:33:18.788 [DEBUG] i.g.h.a.w.f.WsPerformingCheckState - Received matching message {"header":{"cId":103,"name":"ClientAction","code":1,"dType":2}}
20:33:18.789 [DEBUG] i.g.h.a.w.f.WsPerformingCheckState - Current check success
20:33:18.789 [DEBUG] i.g.h.a.w.f.WsPerformingCheckState - Perform next check sequence
20:33:19.233 [TRACE] i.n.h.c.h.w.WebSocket08FrameDecoder - Decoding WebSocket Frame opCode=1
20:33:19.233 [TRACE] i.n.h.c.h.w.WebSocket08FrameDecoder - Decoding WebSocket Frame length=1480
20:33:19.233 [DEBUG] i.g.h.c.i.WebSocketHandler - Read msg=TextWebSocketFrame(data: PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf(ridx: 0, widx: 1480, cap: 1480))
20:33:19.235 [DEBUG] i.g.h.a.w.f.WsPerformingCheckState - Received matching message {"header":{"cId":37,"name":"ClientEvent","dType":2,"dId":1270},"body":{...}}
20:33:19.237 [DEBUG] i.g.h.a.w.f.WsPerformingCheckState - Current check success
20:33:19.238 [DEBUG] i.g.h.a.w.f.WsPerformingCheckState - Perform next check sequence
20:33:20.871 [TRACE] i.n.h.c.h.w.WebSocket08FrameDecoder - Decoding WebSocket Frame opCode=1
20:33:20.871 [TRACE] i.n.h.c.h.w.WebSocket08FrameDecoder - Decoding WebSocket Frame length=65
20:33:20.871 [DEBUG] i.g.h.c.i.WebSocketHandler - Read msg=TextWebSocketFrame(data: PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf(ridx: 0, widx: 65, cap: 65))
20:33:20.872 [DEBUG] i.g.h.a.w.f.WsPerformingCheckState - Received matching message {"header":{"cId":38,"name":"Ping","dType":2}}
20:33:20.872 [DEBUG] i.g.h.a.w.f.WsPerformingCheckState - Current check success
20:33:20.872 [DEBUG] i.g.h.a.w.f.WsPerformingCheckState - Check sequences completed successfully
DUMP---> 2 or 3 responses got
DUMP---> Sending PONG for CLIENT_INITIAL_EVENT
20:33:20.873 [INFO ] i.g.h.a.w.WsSendTextFrame - Sending text frame {"header":{"name":"Ping","cId":38,"dType":1},"body":{}} with websocket 'gatling.http.webSocket': Scenario 'doUntilTimeout', UserId #1
20:33:20.873 [DEBUG] i.g.h.a.w.f.WsIdleState - Send text frame requestPong {"header":{"name":"Ping","cId":38,"dType":1},"body":{}}
20:33:20.873 [DEBUG] i.g.h.c.i.WebSocketHandler - ctx.write msg=TextWebSocketFrame(data: UnpooledByteBufAllocator$InstrumentedUnpooledUnsafeHeapByteBuf(ridx: 0, widx: 65, cap: 256))
20:33:20.873 [TRACE] i.n.h.c.h.w.WebSocket08FrameEncoder - Encoding WebSocket Frame opCode=1 length=65

....

20:33:20.876 [INFO ] i.g.h.a.w.WsSendTextFrame - Sending text frame {"header":{"name":"ClientAction","cId":104,"dType":2},"body":{"type":"NON-INITIAL_CLIENT_EVENT","seqId":304,"data":{...}}} with websocket 'gatling.http.webSocket': Scenario 'doUntilTimeout', UserId #1
20:33:20.876 [DEBUG] i.g.h.a.w.f.WsIdleState - Send text frame requestClientAction {"header":{"name":"CLientAction","cId":104,"dType":2},"body":{"type":"NON-INITIAL_CLIENT_EVENT","seqId":304,"data":{...}}}
20:33:20.876 [DEBUG] i.g.h.c.i.WebSocketHandler - ctx.write msg=TextWebSocketFrame(data: UnpooledByteBufAllocator$InstrumentedUnpooledUnsafeHeapByteBuf(ridx: 0, widx: 167, cap: 512))
20:33:20.876 [TRACE] i.n.h.c.h.w.WebSocket08FrameEncoder - Encoding WebSocket Frame opCode=1 length=167
20:33:20.877 [DEBUG] i.g.h.a.w.f.WsIdleState - Trigger check after sending text frame
20:33:20.897 [TRACE] i.n.h.c.h.w.WebSocket08FrameDecoder - Decoding WebSocket Frame opCode=1
20:33:20.897 [TRACE] i.n.h.c.h.w.WebSocket08FrameDecoder - Decoding WebSocket Frame length=81
20:33:20.897 [DEBUG] i.g.h.c.i.WebSocketHandler - Read msg=TextWebSocketFrame(data: PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf(ridx: 0, widx: 81, cap: 81))
20:33:20.898 [DEBUG] i.g.h.a.w.f.WsPerformingCheckState - Received matching message {"header":{"cId":104,"name":"ClientAction","code":1,"dType":2}}
20:33:20.899 [DEBUG] i.g.h.a.w.f.WsPerformingCheckState - Current check success
20:33:20.899 [DEBUG] i.g.h.a.w.f.WsPerformingCheckState - Perform next check sequence

....

20:33:21.535 [TRACE] i.n.h.c.h.w.WebSocket08FrameDecoder - Decoding WebSocket Frame opCode=1
20:33:21.535 [TRACE] i.n.h.c.h.w.WebSocket08FrameDecoder - Decoding WebSocket Frame length=2275
20:33:21.535 [DEBUG] i.g.h.c.i.WebSocketHandler - Read msg=TextWebSocketFrame(data: PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf(ridx: 0, widx: 2275, cap: 2275))
20:33:21.537 [DEBUG] i.g.h.a.w.f.WsPerformingCheckState - Received matching message {"header":{"cId":39,"name":"ClientEvent","dType":2},"body":{...}}
20:33:21.540 [DEBUG] i.g.h.a.w.f.WsPerformingCheckState - Current check success
20:33:21.540 [DEBUG] i.g.h.a.w.f.WsPerformingCheckState - Check sequences completed successfully
DUMP---> NON-INITIAL_CLIENT_EVENT 2 responses got

....

DUMP---> Sending CLIENT_INITIAL_EVENT and expect 2 or 3 responses. wait for each response for 600 seconds
20:33:21.542 [INFO ] i.g.h.a.w.WsSendTextFrame - Sending text frame {"header":{"name":"ClientAction","cId":105,"dType":2},"body":{...}}} with websocket 'gatling.http.webSocket': Scenario 'doUntilTimeout', UserId #1
20:33:21.542 [DEBUG] i.g.h.a.w.f.WsIdleState - Send text frame requestClientAction {"header":{"name":"ClientAction","cId":105,"dType":2},"body":{...}}}
20:33:21.542 [DEBUG] i.g.h.c.i.WebSocketHandler - ctx.write msg=TextWebSocketFrame(data: UnpooledByteBufAllocator$InstrumentedUnpooledUnsafeHeapByteBuf(ridx: 0, widx: 164, cap: 512))
20:33:21.542 [TRACE] i.n.h.c.h.w.WebSocket08FrameEncoder - Encoding WebSocket Frame opCode=1 length=164
20:33:21.543 [DEBUG] i.g.h.a.w.f.WsIdleState - Trigger check after sending text frame
20:33:21.558 [TRACE] i.n.h.c.h.w.WebSocket08FrameDecoder - Decoding WebSocket Frame opCode=1
20:33:21.559 [TRACE] i.n.h.c.h.w.WebSocket08FrameDecoder - Decoding WebSocket Frame length=81
20:33:21.559 [DEBUG] i.g.h.c.i.WebSocketHandler - Read msg=TextWebSocketFrame(data: PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf(ridx: 0, widx: 81, cap: 81))
20:33:21.560 [DEBUG] i.g.h.a.w.f.WsPerformingCheckState - Received matching message {"header":,"cId":105,"name":"ClientAction","code":1,"dType":2}}
20:33:21.560 [DEBUG] i.g.h.a.w.f.WsPerformingCheckState - Current check success
20:33:21.561 [DEBUG] i.g.h.a.w.f.WsPerformingCheckState - Perform next check sequence
20:33:21.742 [DEBUG] i.g.h.a.w.f.WsPerformingCheckState - Check timeout
20:33:21.743 [DEBUG] i.g.h.a.w.f.WsPerformingCheckState - Check timeout, failing it and performing next action
DUMP---> 2 or 3 responses got
20:33:21.744 [DEBUG] i.g.c.a.Exit - End user #1
20:33:21.748 [DEBUG] i.g.c.c.i.Injector - End user #doUntilTimeout
20:33:21.748 [INFO ] i.g.c.c.i.Injector - All users of scenario doUntilTimeout are stopped
20:33:21.749 [INFO ] i.g.c.c.i.Injector - Stopping
20:33:21.749 [INFO ] i.g.c.c.Controller - Injector has stopped, initiating graceful stop
```

I received the first message from web socket at **20:33:21.560**
Then the second "await" started. It should timeout after 600 seconds,
but in fact I see the timeout right away at **20:33:21.743**

I looks like a bug in Gatling. Something like timeout property reset to zero

Thanks in advance!
Andrei

Comment: It seems like multiple "await" are unstable. They randomly miss the second message. Sometimes I even do not see logs "Perform next check sequence" from the second "await"

Comment: Hi. The bug tracer on Github would be way more suited than StackOverFlow for reporting bugs: https://github.com/gatling/gatling/issues

Comment: Could you please open a ticket on our bugtracker?

Comment: Hello Stephane! Sure, I will file a bug in github. But is it possible in Gatling 3.3.1 to ignore  timeout? For example, I am waiting for a "non-obligatory" message, that may come, but may not come. Both cases must be successful. As far as I understood, the silent websocket feature is added in Gatling 3.4.